# Rendering a heat map for 400.000 points

Tags: c#, performance, wpf

I am trying to draw a heat map with a given input of points and amplitude of each point. The normal input size is around 400000 points, but the code draws every 15th point. The map is drawn onto a `Canvas`.

In the XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="MainPanel" Width="800" Height="600">
    <Textbox Name="textbox" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Canvas Name="canvas" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="450" Margin="70,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="706"/>
</Grid>
```

Rendering code:

```
public static void DrawPoints(Parser parser, Canvas canvas, double radiusX, double radiusY, double thickness, double minAmplitude, double maxAmplitude)
        {
            double cellWidth = canvas.ActualWidth;
            double cellHeight = canvas.ActualHeight;

            var list = parser.Data;

            // Draws every 15th point
            int res = 15;

            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i += res)
            {
                var location = list[i].Point;
                var amplitude = list[i].Amplitude;

                // Converts rgb to hsv values for representation
                var color= ColorConverter.hsv2rgb(
                    COLOR_START_H * (1.0 - ((amplitude - minAmplitude) / (maxAmplitude - minAmplitude))),
                    COLOR_START_S, COLOR_START_V);

                Point center = new Point(location.X, location.Y);
                DrawEllipse(canvas, center, radiusX, radiusY,
                    new SolidColorBrush(color), new SolidColorBrush(color), thickness);
            }
            return;
        }
```

In the `DrawEllipse()` function:

```
public static void DrawEllipse(Canvas canvas, Point center, double radiusX, double radiusY, Brush fill, Brush stroke, double thickness)
        {
            var ellipse = new Ellipse();
            ellipse.Width = radiusX * 2;
            ellipse.Height = radiusY * 2;
            ellipse.Fill = fill;
            ellipse.Stroke = stroke;
            ellipse.StrokeThickness = thickness;

            Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, center.X - radiusX);
            Canvas.SetBottom(ellipse, center.Y - radiusY);

            canvas.Children.Add(ellipse);

            return;
        }
```

In the Main code:

```
private void btnDraw_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Painter.DrawPoints(parser, canvas, 3, 3, 1, 0, 100);
}
```

The issue is that after rendering all the points onto `Canvas`, when I try to enter some text into `textbox` within the same grid, there is significant lag. What can I do to reduce the lag?

Comment: How does the method `DrawEllipse` looks like? That is actually the interesting part ;)

Comment: @JanDotNet oops missed out that part. Updated the question

Comment: _The issue is that after rendering all the points onto Canvas, when I try to enter some text into textbox within the same grid, there is significant lag. What can I do to reduce the lag?_

That is actually a technical problem and therefore off topic. If you are most interested in a solution for that problem I would post the question on stackoverflow again.

Comment: In the interest of posterity, i asked the same question over at stackoverflow and it worked for my case:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45208525/improving-the-rendering-performance-in-drawing-heat-map/45209381?noredirect=1#comment77398769_45209381

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DrawEllipse(canvas, center, radiusX, radiusY,
                    new SolidColorBrush(color), new SolidColorBrush(color), thickness);
```

Creating so much (partially identical) brushes is a waste of resources. Brushes can be easily cached:

```
public static class ColorBrushLookup
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Color, Brush> brushes = new Dictionary<Color, Brush>();

    public static Brush ToCachedBrush(this Color color)
    {
        Brush brush;
        if (!brushes .TryGetValue(color, out brush))
        {
            brush = new SolidColorBrush(color);
            brush.Freeze();
            brushes .Add(color, brush);
        }
        return brush;
    }
}
```

---

Ellipses are relative heavy objects that support layouting, hit testing, drag&drop and so on... If you don't need such features, WPF provides more lightweight ways to draw ellipses to the screen (e.g. [DrawingVisual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.media.drawingvisual(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Using such a lightweight rendering, may also solve your lagging problem (at least if layouting is the problem).

Comment: Worth noting that caching such objects can have it's own resource implications (if you use lots of colours briefly in one part of your program, this static cache will keep them around as baggage for the rest). Personally I'd make this an instanced cache, so it can be collected when/if it becomes redundant, and avoid generally avoid the any misery associated with unexpected off-thread access.

Comment: God point. I just copied it from an project where the static implementation is appropriated. But you are right, it is not a "general purpose" version. However, it is easy to turn it into a instanced cache as you suggest ;)

Comment: A possible way to prevent having too much brush instances in memory is to keep only the last kth ones (eg : using a queue). Another way is to reduce the color depth (eg : to map the 16.7M possible colors to only 512 colors). This can be something simple such as ´color = Color.FromArgb(color.R&0xE0, color.G&0xE0, color.B&0xE0)`

Comment: @tigrou I generally shy away from any 'smart' cache management unless I know well the domain it will be working it. If a program uses `k+1` brushes in a cyclic fashion, such a k-last cache will provide significant overhead with no benefit. This is not to say that the idea is not a good one, but one needs to fully contemplate how it is going to be used.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you need some sort of high level interaction with those points, to create 400,000 shapes (which are `FrameworkElement`, all but lightweight) is a waste of time and resources.

Did you consider to **use an image**, drawing them inside a `WriteableImage` and to display the image instead? Check MSDN for `DrawingVisual` and `DrawingContext` subjects. I used this method for small multiples composed with *really* huge heatmaps and it worked like a charm. Simple hittesting (for example to show a tooltip with exact value) is trivial to implement using X-Y coordinates.

You will keep your visual tree almost empty, you won't create few thousands brushes each time (but you can create your color palette once and use it multiple times) and redrawing will be as fast as you want. In most applications you don't need an *infinite* number of color shades, consider to **limit palette** to 256 entries and to map values to those **discrete values**.

You will need to create an image with the proper size but this has a great advantage:

- When redrawing is requested then immediately create a very **low-res image** with few hundred points.
- Start a **background thread** to draw the full-resolution image (using current canvas size).
- When image is ready then simply replace the old low-res one.

In this way you can even easily debounce multiple requests caused by resize operations (if you care at all).

Note: to pick one point every N is not a proper **decimation method** because it doesn't preserve local minimum and maximum; you may (will!) visualize *wrong* results. Consider using minmax or, only if your type of data allows it, at least an average.